# Extract everything before second last hyphen in Perl

Tags: perl, join, split

I'm trying to extract everything before second last hyphen in any given rpm. I have this working by specifying the index numbers, however this does not work for strings with a different number of hyphens. I know the release is after the last hyphen, the version is after the second last hyphen, and the name is everything before that. How can I do this with perl?

This is what I currently have:

```
my $str = "rpm-python-4.8.0-55";
my $name = join '-', (split /-/, $str)[-4 .. -3];
my $version = (split /-/, $str)[-2];
my $release = (split /-/, $str)[-1];

print "Name: $name\n";
print "Version: $version\n";
print "Release: $release\n";
```

Output:

```
Name: rpm-python
Version: 4.8.0
Release: 55
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know you need the last two items separated, release and version.

```
my @items = split '-', $str;

my $release = pop @items;
my $version = pop @items;

my $package_name = join '-', @items;
```

Or, you can use a regex

```
my ($package, $version, $release) = $str =~ m/(.*)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$/;
```

Comment: Thanks @zdim! The regex one-liner is the winner

Comment: @MikeA  Thanks -- regex is indeed nice that way.  Until the "one-liner" turns into a three-line nightmare trying to encode half of the Universe :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is a regex. The following example will capture everything including hyphens until it hits a hyphen, anything, another hyphen and then the rest.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @strings = qw(
    rpm-python-4.8.0-55
    rpm-one-two-three-four-1.1.1-22
);

for (@strings){
    my ($name, $version, $release) = /(.*)-(.*)-(.*)/;
    print "Name: $name\n";
    print "Version: $version\n";
    print "Release: $release\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Name: rpm-python
Version: 4.8.0
Release: 55

Name: rpm-one-two-three-four
Version: 1.1.1
Release: 22
```